Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kohsuke/github/GHFileNotFoundException
I run a project in IntelijIdea with no problem. When I try to run from the commands like this:

Set your GitHub Personal Access Token as an environment variable named GITHUB_TOKEN.
Build the application using the command mvn clean install.
After a successful build, a github-analyzer.jar file will be generated in the target directory.
Navigate to the target directory using the command cd target.
Run the application using the command java -jar github-analyzer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.`

maven runs, but in the last commnand I get this error:

Error: Unable to initialize main class GitHubAnalyzer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/kohsuke/github/GHFileNotFoundException

This is my code, am I doing anything wrong?
import org.kohsuke.github.*;
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GitHubAnalyzer {
    public static String GITHUB_TOKEN;

    static {
        Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
        GITHUB_TOKEN = dotenv.get("GITHUB_TOKEN");
    }
    public static final long WEEK_IN_MILLIS = 7L * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if(GITHUB_TOKEN.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Please set the GITHUB_TOKEN environment variable");
            return;
        }
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("GitHub Analyzer");
            System.out.println("Insert owner:");
            String owner = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Insert repository:");
            String repository = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("What do you want to analyze?");
            System.out.println("1. Pair of contributors that worked on the same file");
            System.out.println("2. Contributions of contributors in the last week");
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();

            GitHub github;
            try {
                github = new GitHubBuilder().withOAuthToken(GITHUB_TOKEN).build();
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.err.println("An error occurred while accessing GitHub: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            analyzeRepository(github, owner, repository, choice);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error occurred while analyzing the repository: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private static void analyzeRepository(GitHub github, String owner, String repository, int choice) throws IOException {
        GHRepository repo;
        try {
            repo = github.getRepository(owner + "/" + repository);
        } catch (GHFileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Repository not found");
            return;
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("An error occurred while accessing the repository: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        List<GHCommit> commits = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            commits = repo.listCommits().withPageSize(100).toList();

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("An error occurred while accessing the repository: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }


        int numOfCommits = commits.size();
        Map<String,List<GHCommit>> commitsByAuthor = commits.stream()
                .filter(commit -> {
                    try {
                        return commit.getAuthor() != null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(commit -> {
                    try {
                        return commit.getAuthor().getLogin();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
        }));

        List<GHRepository.Contributor> contributors = repo.listContributors().toList();
        Date weekAgo = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - WEEK_IN_MILLIS);
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Map<String,Set<String>> contributorsFileMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        if (choice == 1) {
            analyzeContributorsPairs(repo, commits, numOfCommits, counter, contributorsFileMap, contributors);
        } else if(choice == 2){
            analyzeContributorsContributions(repo, commitsByAuthor, weekAgo, counter, contributors);
        }


    }

    private static void analyzeContributorsContributions(GHRepository repo, Map<String, List<GHCommit>> commitsByAuthor, Date weekAgo, AtomicInteger counter, List<GHRepository.Contributor> contributors) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Analyzing contributors contributions");
        for(GHRepository.Contributor contributor:contributors){
            List<GHCommit> commitsByThisAuthor = commitsByAuthor.getOrDefault(contributor.getLogin(),Collections.emptyList());
            analyzeContributor(repo, contributor, weekAgo,commitsByThisAuthor);
        }
    }

    private static void analyzeContributorsPairs(GHRepository repo, List<GHCommit> commits, int numOfCommits, AtomicInteger counter, Map<String, Set<String>> contributorsFileMap, List<GHRepository.Contributor> contributors) {
        System.out.println("Analyzing contributors pairs");
        commits.forEach((commit)-> parseCommit(commit, counter, numOfCommits, contributorsFileMap));
        displayResult(getTopPairs(contributorsFileMap));
    }

    private static void analyzeContributor(GHRepository repo, GHRepository.Contributor contributor, Date weekAgo, List<GHCommit> commitsByThisAuthor) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Analyzing contributor: " + contributor.getLogin());
        int linesOfCode = 0;
        int commitsNo;
        int mergeRequests;
        int maxCharsInComment = 0;

        List<GHCommit> commits = commitsByThisAuthor.stream()
                .filter(commit -> {
                    try {
                        return commit.getCommitDate().after(weekAgo);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        commitsNo = commits.size();

        for(GHCommit commit : commits) {
            for(GHCommit.File file : commit.getFiles()) {
                linesOfCode += file.getLinesAdded();
            }
        }

        List<GHPullRequest> pullRequests = repo.getPullRequests(GHIssueState.ALL)
                .stream().filter(ghPullRequest -> {
                    try {
                        return (ghPullRequest.getUser().getLogin().equals(contributor.getLogin()) && ghPullRequest.getCreatedAt().after(weekAgo));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        mergeRequests = pullRequests.size();

        List<GHPullRequestReviewComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
        pullRequests.stream().map(ghPullRequest -> {
            try {
                return ghPullRequest.listReviewComments();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).forEach(ghPullRequestReviewComments -> {
            try {
                comments.addAll(ghPullRequestReviewComments.toList());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        maxCharsInComment = comments.stream().
                map(GHPullRequestReviewComment::getBody).
                map(String::length).max(Integer::compareTo).orElse(0);

        System.out.println("Contributor: " + contributor.getLogin());
        System.out.println("Lines of code: " + linesOfCode);
        System.out.println("Commits: " + commitsNo);
        System.out.println("Merge requests: " + mergeRequests);
        System.out.println("Max chars in comment: " + maxCharsInComment);
        System.out.println("\n\n");


    }

    private static List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> getTopPairs(Map<String, Set<String>> contributorsFileMap) {
        Map<String, Integer> pairFrequency = new HashMap<>();
        for(Set<String> contributors : contributorsFileMap.values()) {
            List<String> contributorList = new ArrayList<>(contributors);
            for(int i = 0; i < contributorList.size(); i++) {
                for(int j = i + 1; j < contributorList.size(); j++) {
                    String pair = contributorList.get(i) + " - " + contributorList.get(j);
                    pairFrequency.put(pair, pairFrequency.getOrDefault(pair, 0) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return pairFrequency.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    private static void displayResult(List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedPairs) {
        if(sortedPairs.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("\n\nNo contributors pairs found");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nTop contributors pairs:");
        sortedPairs.stream().limit(10).forEach(pair -> {
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue());
        });
    }

    private static void parseCommit(GHCommit commit, AtomicInteger counter, int numOfCommits, Map<String, Set<String>> contributorsFileMap) {
        int count = counter.incrementAndGet();
        int percentage = (int) (((double) count / numOfCommits) * 100);
        getProgressBar(percentage);

        try {
            Optional.ofNullable(commit.getAuthor())
                    .map(GHPerson::getLogin)
                    .ifPresent(author->{
                        try {
                            commit.getFiles().stream().map(GHCommit.File::getFileName).forEach(filename -> {
                                contributorsFileMap.computeIfAbsent(filename, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(author);
                            });
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void getProgressBar(int percentage) {
        StringBuilder progressBar = new StringBuilder("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if(i < percentage / 2) {
                progressBar.append("=");
            } else {
                progressBar.append(" ");
            }
        }
        progressBar.append("] " + percentage + "%");
        System.out.print("\r" + progressBar.toString());
    }
}




Does your 'pom.xml' for the project have org.kohsuke.github as a dependency?
Given no class defined error that would be the first place I'd look.
https://github-api.kohsuke.org/dependencies.html
